# Netgear Nighthawk R6700v2 router can't connect to the Internet via a Comcast/Xfinity cable modem

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, cable-modem

Note: I'm offering this self-answered question hoping it will spare others similar troubles. I don't know what other Netgear router models are affected.

**Prerequisites:**

- The Comcast/Xfinity cable modem itself has Internet connectivity (verifiable via a direct-to-a-computer Ethernet connection) and - if the modem isn't just a modem but also has a Wifi router built in (residential gateway) - it must be in [*bridge mode*](https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/wireless-gateway-enable-disable-bridge-mode).
- The cable modem has been power-cycled and given enough time to come online before you've connected the router to it by Ethernet cable. When in doubt, power-cycle both devices and do not reconnect the router until the cable modem is back online.

**Symptoms:**

- The **router never manages to connect to the Internet via the cable modem** - the Internet-connectivity LED on the device remains *orange* (white is what indicates an established connection)
- The router's web-based administration application at http://192.168.1.1 tries to connect, fails, offers to try again, and keeps failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Presumably*, the *automated* setup fails, because **the router unexpectedly submits an account-name field containing the router's model number** when trying to register with Comcast's WAN.

The workaround is to **configure the connection *manually***:

- Connect to the router's web-based administration application at http://192.168.1.1

  - If the page was previously open, refresh it.
- This will trigger an automatic setup attempt - wait for it it to fail.
- On failure, choose the option "I want to set it up myself" (or similar wording).
- On the manual configuration page:

  - **Clear the "Account Name (If Required)" field** (the password field should be empty anyway).
  - **Set all other options to either "Dynamic" (IP address) or "Automatic" (DNS server addresses, MAC address)**
  - Click "Apply", at which point, after a minute or so, the connection should succeed: a new page should tell you so, and the router's LED should have turned white.